# java.lang.NullPointerException when POST with AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, asynchttpclient

I have an endpoint `/test` which expects `Map` :

```
 @POST("/hello")
    @PermitAll
    public JSONObject test(Map param) throws JsonParseException {
    String elementName = param.get("name").toString();
    String elem = param.get("elem").toString();
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("id",1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

And I'm sending asynchronous POST (postin JSON) using `AsyncHttpClient`:

```
public static void asyncCallPost(JSONObject jsonData) throws Exception {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        try { 
            Response response = client.preparePost(url) 
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") 
                    .addHeader("Content-Length", "" + jsonData.length()) 
                    .setBody(jsonData.toString()).execute().get(); 
            if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) { 
                throw new Exception("Error ");
            } 
        } finally { 
            client.close(); 
        } 
    }
```

But I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
Is it because I don't pass any Map to `/hello`? If so how make `POST` with `jsonData` as `Map` to the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell without further information however I suspect that the following needs to change;

```
String elementName = param.get("name").toString();
String elem = param.get("elem").toString();
```

to

```
String elementName;
if(param.get("name") != null){
   elementName = param.get("name").toString();
}
String elem;
if(param.get("elem") != null){
   elem = param.get("elem").toString();
}
```

The reason being the param.get("name") is returning a null which you are attempting to run toString on, hence the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a JSON string to the body, that's why the Map is null or empty or full of garbage (I didn't check myself).

The Map is a representation of the key-value pairs that are POSTed. To have the Map non-empty, you would have to post e.g. `name=myname&elem=myelement` as type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I tiried POSTing with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but I got same error.

Comment: What did you try to POST in the body? Was it the string I gave you: `name=myname&elem=myelement` or the JSON again?